# Reconstruct line plugin in Qgis 3.X

Tags: qgis-3, line, points-to-line

I've been using reconstruct line in Qgis 2.18 and it a wonderful plug-in to create line between selected point.

Now I'm on Qgis 3.4 and all I can find it plug in that add line everywhere (not only selected point).

Anybody knows of a plugin in that I can use that have the same principle than Reconstruct line, Get point then Create line?

Comment: There is the `Points to path` tool in the _Processing Toolbox_ you could try.

Comment: Thx for ur answer but Sadly point to path take everything in the point layer i cannot select just a few point and make line  ( my point represent electric pole and the line would represent the networks) so i need to make a line only for the selected point)

Comment: But you can enable the `Selected features only` option :)

Comment: Omg im soo blind thx so much u just saved my day

Comment: But it make one single line is it possible to split those line after?

Comment: You could try SAGA's `Split lines at points` tool, again from the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: Sadly it dosent seem to work i tryed multiple time and it kinna does the oposite it create line that goes to africa instead of splitting them

Comment: i just noticed the command Explode line works thx so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

There is the Points to path tool in the Processing Toolbox you could try. – Joseph 
But you can enable the Selected features only option :) – Joseph
command Explode line  to make multiple lines from 1 line